# Jquery mobile and toggleClass to make a navbar li a have an on and off state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, toggleclass

http://rickgutierrez.bol.ucla.edu/navbartest.html

This is my basic jquery mobile navigation setup. I am attempting to get the first three navbar elements to function more like toggles with an on and off state; click the button and it switches to the other state (without affecting an of the other buttons states), click it again and it switches back. When the page loads, 1 is in the on state which is styled by .ui-btn-active and 2, 3, 4 are in the off state; I am not quite sure what part of the jquery mobile css code styles the off state. There are also ui-btn-up-a and ui-btn-down-a styles which I think may be relevant.

After some research I came across several toggleClass tutorials:
http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

The first demo on the jquery tutorial is closest to what I am looking for with the independent functionality. The code in that demos is straight forward and simple which is why I am frustrated that I cannot make it work on my page.

Can anyone offer some pointers? Which classes should I be using? Is toggleClass in the jquery mobile library or do I need to add a link to the latest jquery script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a code using JsBin. Hope it helps: http://jsbin.com/exenov/4/edit

I've added a new class (custom-btn-active), which I use in the jQuery on click function.

The only thing you should do in your jquerymobile.css file is to DELETE the original `.ui-btn-active` css. Because I can't remove that class with the use of jQuery (I have absolutely no idea why)

Check my Jsbin > the button stays green on click, and when clicked again it goes off (don't pay attention to the blue background because that is the .ui-btn-active which you need to delete).

Comment: I made the changes you suggested substituting in what I think are the correct css styles and the menu items are functioning the same as they did before. You can see the changes on the link.

Comment: http://rickgutierrez.bol.ucla.edu/navbartest.html Finally got it working correctly. I also don't completely understand why I could not get the function to work with jquery mobiles existing CSS styles. I ended up renaming the old active class and following your example on the jquery function. Thanks!!